# IE8 Regular expression not working

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-8

Does anyone know how to make that work in IE8 ?

```
var html = (function () {/*   <!DOCTYPE html>   <html>
    <body>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    </body>   </html>        
*/}).toString().match(/[^]*\/\*([^]*)\*\/\}$/)[1];
```

Chrome returns this (which is the expected answer)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    </body>
  </html>
```

but IE8 doesn't like it, it returns

```
  '/' expected
```

I have verified the toString() part in IE8 and it contains

```
"(function () {/*   <!DOCTYPE html>   <html>
        <body>
          <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        </body>   </html>        
    */})"
```

The goal is to extract what is in comment, so it's possible to use multiline string in javascript without any added character.
So if someone comes up with another regular expression that works in IE8 and Chrome that would be great.

Comment: What's the problem you get in IE 8. It's always good to make a **demo** that people can see. This way you will get your answer quicker and easier.

Comment: How is this working in Chrome?

Comment: Yes. What is your expected output, and what is your actual output?

Comment: Have you tried removing the regex part? Maybe it's `.toString()` that's failing.

Comment: Safari says `TypeError: 'null' is not an object (near '...*\/\*([^]*)\*\/\}$/)[1];...')`.

Answer (score 0):

The `toString` method applied to a function does not necessarily return the source code exactly as typed. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) says "toString decompiles the function, and the string returned includes the function keyword, the argument list, curly braces, and the source of the function body". It also shows this to be non standard and obsolete. The ECMAscript standard has the following to say :

> 15.3.4.2   Function.prototype.toString ( )
>
> An implementation-dependent representation of the function is returned. This
>   representation has the syntax of a FunctionDeclaration. Note in particular
>   that the use and placement of white space, line terminators, and semicolons
>   within the representation String is implementation-dependent.
>
> The toString function is not generic; it throws a TypeError exception if its
>   this value is not a Function object. Therefore, it cannot be transferred to
>    other kinds of objects for use as a method.

I hesitate to say that all JS implementations support function.toString, but I know of none that do not. Their implementation varies however. Chrome seems to return the full source including comments, Firefox removes comments.

I had the same idea as yours to use comments to pass information but abandoned it when I found that Firefox removed them.

All that said, since toString **is** returning the comment string there must be an issue with the RE. No having an IE8 available for testing I cannot suggest a definitive fix but you might try the following :

```
 /\/\*([^]*?)\*\/\}$/
```

I have removed the superfluous [^]* at the start and made the capturing [^]* non-greedy.
Both your original version and my changed one work in my Chrome Browser.

Comment: >>source.match(/\/\*([^]*?)\*\/\}$/)
  "']' expected in regular expression"

Comment: Hmm, Chrome has no issue with that. Try replacing the `[^]` with `[.\n\r]`

Comment: source.match(/\/\*([.\n\r]*?)\*\/\}$/)
 => null

Comment: Since we seem to be making some progress try /\/\*([^q]*?)\*\/\}$/ There is no q in your sample.

Comment: var html = (function () {/*   <!DOCTYPE html>   <html>      <body>        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>      </body>   </html>          */}).toString().match( /\/*([^q]*?)*\/\}$/)  <= this crash ie8 , not responding any more )